# Using getter and setter with Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I want to convert a data property to accessor property using Object.defineProperty() . Consider the code for this which leads to `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error

```
var c = { name: 'abcde'};
Object.defineProperty(c, 'name', {
    get: function() {
        return this.name; //causes stack overflow
    },
    set: function(x) {
       this.name = x; //causes stack overflow
        }
}); 
c.name="xyz";  
console.log(c.name);
```

I understood why the error crops in.
One of the proposed solution is to remove 'this' from getter and setter and it seems to work.

```
var c = { name: 'abcde'};
Object.defineProperty(c, 'name', {
    get: function() {
        return name; //removed this
    },
    set: function(x) {
       name = x; //removed this
        }
}); 
c.name="xyz";  
console.log(c.name);
```

What is happening ? In general , I want to ask how to convert a data property to accessor property using Object.defineProperty() ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second code *doesn't actually work* because it uses the *global* variable called `name` to store the value, instead of storing it in the object `c`.

It would be rejected by ES5 "strict mode", if it weren't for the fact that `window.name` is a default property of the global object in browsers.

A more appropriate fix would be to store the value in a lexically scoped private variable:

```
var c = (function() {
    var obj = {};
    var name = "abcde";

    Object.defineProperty(obj, "name", {
        get: function() {
            return name;
        },
        set: function(x) {
            name = x;
        }
    });

    return obj;
})();
```

Comment: Awesome solution. But how can then I convert a data property like 'name' here to accessor property? here you have kept name in closure. I want it initially as data property.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin AFAIK, the only other way is to shadow a real property, and then just use naming conventions (e.g. a leading underscore) to mark the real property as "private", so e.g. you could use `._name` to store the actual value, but access it via `.name`.

Comment: It's so weird. If you remove getter function and **define only setter function**, the property name will be undefined even you have been declared it. Why?